# Google Colab recent error: OSError: libcudart.so.10.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, google-colaboratory, pytorch-geometric

I was successfully running the PyTorch Geometric Graph Classification popular example Google Colab notebook event last week: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1I8a0DfQ3fI7Njc62__mVXUlcAleUclnb?usp=sharing

But today (Mon 10/11/2021) running the same is throwing error " OSError: libcudart.so.10.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory ". This probably coming from executing the following "from torch_geometric.datasets import TUDataset". (I already made sure the runtime type is selected as GPU.)